# Python equivalent of a Visual-Studio project (or solution)

Tags: python, module, project, solution

Is there a standard file in python which lists all the modules comprising the project, and other metadata?

Is this simply the 'package'? Or, do different IDEs use their own specific files?

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't a single file in any package that consistently lists every module the entire package imports. Some people make entries to the `__init__.py` and some don't. Usually most python supported IDE's will make available to you whatever is on your pythonpath. Eclipse pydev, for instance, will add the specific project to the pythonpath of that project space.

If your project is on the pythonpath, then it should resolve.

Application builders like py2app/py2exe will scan the entire project and create an import graph to discover every module needed for that project

Answer (score 0):

There's no real equivalent in Python by itself.  Python packages are the way to encapsulate a set of modules and include metadata, but it isn't exactly equivalent to the notion of a "project."

Otherwise, are some projects which use project files in order to give you some of the features which IDEs provide.  In particular, you should check out the [`rope`](http://rope.sourceforge.net/) library and the [PyCharm IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) for some systems which implement a project file.